# What domain maps to $[-1,1]\times[-1,1]$ under $e^z$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

Looking over my complex mid term from earlier in the year, and the bonus question is to find a domain such that $e^z$ maps bijectively onto "The unit square"  ie) maps to the square with vertices $1,-1,i,-1$.
Lets say for $w$ in the square I let $w=x+iy$ then this range can be expressed as $-1<x<1$ and $-1<y<1$ (Equality should be allowed here too, but I'm not sure how to type less than or equal).  If I just apply the complex $\DeclareMathOperator{\Log}{Log} \Log$ to these inequalities (choosing a suitable branch and 'ignoring' my issue at $0$ for a moment) I just get another square, but I'm sure that can't be right.
My suspicion is that the domain should look like an 'inverse circle'.  Like a diamond shape but smoothly concave.

Comment: Why can we ignore 0?

Answer (score 2):

We are given the square $Q:=[{-1},1]^2$ in the $(u,v)$-plane ad have to find the $z=x+iy\in{\mathbb  C}$ with $e^z\in Q$. Since $e^z=e^{x+iy}=e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)$ we have to describe the set $S$ of points $(x,y)$ satisfying
$$|e^x\cos y|\leq1,\quad |e^x\sin y|\leq 1\ ,$$or 
$$\max\{|\cos y|,|\sin y|\}\leq e^{-x}\ .$$
Given $y\in{\mathbb R}$ this amounts to
$$x\leq-\log\max\{|\cos y|,|\sin y|\}=:\psi(y)\ .$$
The following figure shows a graph of the funcion $\psi$.

[image]
The set $S$ in question  can then be written as
$$S=\bigl\{z=x+iy\>\big|\>-\infty< y<\infty,\ x\leq\psi(y)\bigr\}\ ,$$
whereby a vertical copy of the above curve, the bubbles showing to the left, serves as right boundary of $S$.

Comment: So then the set of points whose x coordinates are between negative pi and pi, and whose y values range from 0 to the blue curve, maps bijectively onto the square in the u-v plane?

Comment: **No**. The points $(x,y)$ with $y$ ranging from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, and $x$ ranging from $-\infty$ to the $90^\circ$ clockwise rotated blue curve map into $Q$. Points differing by $2k\pi$ in $y$-direction map onto the same point in $Q$. The origin in $Q$ is not assumed by the map.